# Exporting classnames using Monteverdi

Tags: export, classification, orfeo-toolbox

i managed to get my rgb-Image classified with Monteverdi. I discribed 8 classes with different classnames. For my work i dont need the rgb-values, i just need the classnames. Is there any way to export my classification result as vector file? Or can i save the information about the classname? I was just able to export my classification result as tif-file. So my input file contains 3-Band rgb values and my exported file has the same as well, just different values.

Iam open for all suggestions. Thanks.

Update: I am still not able to export my resulting classes. All i get is a 3-band rgb images regardless whether i choose *.img or *.tif. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

generally the output of a classification is an image label which is a grey scale image where each pixel value is an integer which correspond to a class.

You can convert this label image to a RGB image, this operation is called color mapping (using a look up table for instance to affect a RGB value for each class value).

There is an OTB application called **ColorMapping** which allow to do this

To vectorize your output you can have a look to the **gdal_polygonize** utility:

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html

or try also the OTB **Rasterization** application.

Note also that all the OTB applications cited and available through command line or interactively in the new version of Monteverdi (Monteverdi 2 version 0.6)

Regards,

Manuel

Comment: Hi Manuel, first of all thanks for your answer. What you discribed first is exactly what i want to have. Unfortunately i used ".tiff as export file format. So i got another tiff-Image with rgb values instant of grayscale image representing classes. Which file format do i have to choose to get a grayscale image?                                                  How can i use the otb commands in the new Monteverdi version 2? As i used the gui i was just able to scrool, zoom and get information about the histogramm etc. Best regards